# How to load properties file using spring framework in file system

Tags: java, spring, properties

Now I'm trying to load properties file in computer file system in my desktop application using spring framework. configuration folder have two files: `datasource-tx-jpa.xml` and `database.properties` (both files locate at same folder). But when I run this application then a message box appear with message `can not load ${sqlserver.jdbc.driverClassName} in dataSource`. Below is configuration of `datasource-tx-jpa.xml`.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:database.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${sqlserver.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${sqlserver.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${sqlserver.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${sqlserver.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: How are you loading the context and currently it is looking in the current directory for those files.

Comment: applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:J:/DungXNguyen/resources/jpa-app-context.xml");

Comment: jpa-app-context.xml, datasource-tx-jpa.xml, database.properties are in same folder (resources)

Comment: Try `file:./database.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for all your support. It works

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is on your resources folder, you can use `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:database.properties" />`